# Best way to get current site's address in the view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've built this application and I have this line in my view:

```
<a ng-href="https://www.mysite.ca/_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId={{group.id}}" target="_blank">{{group.name}}</td></a>
```

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to make the "https://www.mysite.ca" dynamic so I can easily move my application to different domains and not have to worry about remembering to update the domain everytime since I have these sort of links in a few places

From what I can see there's about 3-4 options:

1. Use a `.value("configs",{Root_Url: location.origin})`
2. `$rootScope` and inject it into the controller for each view
3. I could use a service and inject that
4. Or instead of a value use a constant / `$provide`?

Ideally, I'd like to bypass the controller altogether if that's possible at all. If not however, if not, what would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: value or constant + $rootScope in the run block imo

Comment: Personally I use fourth variant...

Comment: Any reason you cannot just drop the entire domain name and just make it relative from root, like `<a ng-href="/_layouts/people.aspx?....`

Comment: @Whisher I added this to the run block '$rootScope.Site_URL = location.origin' and it seems to have done the trick. I didn't use a value or constant for it though. Is that okay?

Comment: @Soren mostly preference. I'd like to solidify the path so I know what it's referencing every time. Using a relative path I feel would complicate things a bit depending on where I was installing the application and where the files are stored (ie. Home Page or subsites, etc).

Comment: @Batman -- relative to root, would not change that at all -- it would just mean that the browser would determine the http-https part as well as the host name to be used, but you would have absolute paths from root.

Comment: @Batman it's quite the same in a service (constant,value,factory etc) is better because you heave got separation of concerns